# Error trying to switch between different charts

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I am developing an application which shows the data created in a chartjs graph, what I am doing it does well, since all the data is displayed in the way I want, but I have a problem and that is that now I am trying to do that according to the type of graph that a user wants this to be changed, the problem is that the graph is changed but in case of having multiple graphs only the first graph is changed, the others continue with the graph by default, this is my template:

```
<select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChart()" data-role="select">
    <option value="pie">pie</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<canvas id="{{ project.slug }}" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

This is my script:

```
var faltante = 100 - {{ project.porcent }};

var data = {
    labels: ['{{ project.name }}', 'Falta'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [{{ project.porcent }}, faltante],
        backgroundColor: ['#252850', '#f44611']
    }],
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('{{ project.slug }}').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data
});

function updateChart() {
    myChart.destroy();
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: document.getElementById("chartType").value,
        data: data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke your `updateChart` function with the selected chart type as follows:

```
onchange="updateChart(this.value)"
```

Everything could then be done inside the `updateChart` function.

1. destroy the chart if it already exists
2. create the new chart with the specified type

To make this work, you'll also have to explicitly invoke `updateChart` once with the initial chart type.

```
updateChart('pie');
```

Please take a look at below runnable code snippet and see how it works.

```js
let myChart;
function updateChart(type) {
  if (myChart) {
    myChart.destroy();
  }
  myChart = new Chart('chart', {
    type: type,
    data: {
      labels: ['A', 'B'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [3, 6],
        backgroundColor: ['#252850', '#f44611']
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          display: type == 'bar',
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
}
updateChart('pie');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChart(this.value)" data-role="select">
  <option value="pie">Pie</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<canvas id="chart" height="100"></canvas>
```